# Get last element of Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with the Youtube Data Api V3 and this array is beeing returned from my api call:

[image]

What i want:

I wanna access the red underlined Array in the Image above and respectively get the latest array inside of it. (In the example i wanna access the [maxres], but it's always different)

What i tried:

```
$var = end($array)['url']; // $array is my input array
```

But that doesn't work and so i hope someone can help me :)

Comment: This not the end array from Youtube, you are accessing array inbetween API's. You tube will provide exact and more granular array with keys.

Comment: Check equivalent API call from your website to Youtube

Comment: how do you access to protected property, `modelData`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `array_pop`. [Link to PHP documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
<?pnp
$var = array_pop($array['modelData:protected']);
```

Comment: `modelData:protected` means that `modelData` is a protected attribute, it's not a key name.

Answer (score 0):

`$object->modelData` is a protected property, you cannot access it. Usually there is a function included in the object to retrieve it.

For example `$array = $object->getModelData();`

But if it was not protected, this would be a solution:

```
$array = $object->modelData;
end($array);
$key = key($array);
var_dump($object->modelData[$key];
```

Comment: `modelData` is a protected attribute, not public, you can't directly access to it.

Comment: I haven't noticed that bit, i'll incorporate it into the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
$var = $array['url'][ count($array['url']) - 1 ]
```

Comment: Whilst this method would work, it is not preferred since PHP has a built in method to do exactly as the OP wants.

Comment: Actually, this wouldn't work at all and would create parse errors: `$array['url'].length` is incorrect and should be `count($array['url'])`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, got my languages mixed up :)